# Angular, GitHub API, Return repositories and tags

Tags: javascript, git, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and also fairly novice when it comes to js. I'm trying to return a list of repositories and with each one, list it's tags. I have managed to get the repositories  with the following controller and factory.

```
//Controller
claGitHub.controller('repoController', function ($scope, reposFactory) {

    reposFactory.getRepos().success(function(result){
        $scope.repos = result;
        console.log(result)
    });

});

//Factory
claGitHub.factory('reposFactory', ['$http', function($http){

    var repos = [];

    repos.getRepos = function() {
        return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/google/repos');
    };

    return repos;

}]);
```

Using Angular, I can iterate through each object and output it's properties in my view, woo! The problem is the tags property is a nested JSON feed rather than links to the actual tag urls. e.g.

```
tags_url: "https://api.github.com/repos/google/autoparse/tags"
```

So I have tried iterating through each object, making another AJAX call based on it's tags_url property with limited success. My patchy knowledge has meant I simply can't work out where it should go and how it should look syntactically. Do I make another factory and controller? Or should it be part of the existing code? Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's my view for good measure:

```
<!-- Repeating section for featured repositories -->
<div data-ng-repeat="repo in repos" class="repo-tile">
    <h2>{{repo.name}}</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>{{repo.description}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest wrapping up the whole process of getting/formatting the data in the repos service.

The code below returns the repos with promises for the tags, you could also wrap the whole response in a promise that waited for all tags to return, but it'd probably be better to progressively render than wait till it's all there.

```
claGitHub.factory('reposFactory', ['$http', function($http){

    var repos = {};

    repos.getRepos = function() {
        return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/google/repos')
        .then(function(resp) {
          return resp.data.map(function(repo) {
            $http.get(repo.tags_url).then(function(resp) {
              repo.tags = resp.data
            })
            return repo
          })
        })

    };

    return repos;

}]);
```

You can then bind to each repo's `.tags` property, which'll start off `undefined` and eventually pop into a list of tags once the `tags_url` request resolves.

By the way, avoid suffixing providers with things like 'Factory': it's not important to the code calling it if it's defined via a factory or service.

You also had `repos` as a `[]` - switched to an `{}`.

Comment: I think the first ".then(function(repos)" should be ".then(function(resp)"? Just tried that and it works really well, that's real nice! Thanks so much.